Scroll parent container when items inside are resized towards the end of the container
I am using dnd timeline (based on dnd-kit) to generate a timeline which has items that are resizable. I am also defining a certain width per second, and it is set in such a way that the timeline will always fit to its container width. However, later if the items are resized then the timeline may overflow.
What I am trying to achieve is that on resizing the item towards the end, I want the container to start scrolling so that the item keeps resizing.
An example of such behavior is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Oig6fSib2fwlCOUj6cQCvSgt18NZwYH/view?usp=sharing
I have also created a sandbox with a dummy environment. Please let me know if anyone has any idea on how this can be done smoothly, such that the cursor, scroll and items right end (or left in the other case) aligns.
